# How do I FilterExpression by datetime OR text?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Good afternoon, the user should be able to search by both date and text, how do I do both in one textbox?

[image]

```
protected void BtnWinnersSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string searchText = txtWinnersSearch.Text.Replace("'", "''").Trim();
    GridViewWinners.Visible = true;

    SqlDataSource4.FilterExpression = "nickname like '%" + searchText + "%' or username like '%" + searchText +
        "%' or clubnumber like '%" + searchText + "%' or firstname like '%" +
        searchText + "%' or lastname like '%" + searchText +
        "%' or email like '%" + searchText + "%' or dob like '%" + Convert.ToDateTime(searchText).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "%'";
}
```

Throws the following error:

[image]

[image]

Works!

Comment: is dob a datetime column?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I got it. Here's the answer:

> ```
>     public static bool IsDate(Object obj)
>     {
>         string strDate = obj.ToString();
>         try
>         {
>             DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(strDate);
>             if (dt != DateTime.MinValue && dt != DateTime.MaxValue)
>                 return true;
>             return false;
>         }
>         catch
>         {
>             return false;
>         }
>     }
>
> protected void BtnWinnersSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>
>         string searchText = txtWinnersSearch.Text.Replace("'", "''").Trim();
>         bool isDate = IsDate(searchText);
>
>         GridViewWinners.Visible = true;
>
>         if (isDate == true)
>         {
>             SqlDataSource4.FilterExpression = "dob" + " ='" + Convert.ToDateTime(searchText).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'";
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             SqlDataSource4.FilterExpression = "nickname like '%" + searchText + "%' or username like '%" + searchText +
>                 "%' or clubnumber like '%" + searchText + "%' or firstname like '%" +
>                 searchText + "%' or lastname like '%" + searchText +
>                 "%' or email like '%" + searchText + "%'";
>         }
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You should never - ever - write SQL Code like that! Your code it horribly vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.

If searchText is something like "'; truncate table; --" then you're dead in the water.

There's also no practical way to protect yourself via Regex validation. Any Regex you can come up with can be worked around via any number of vectors.

Seriously, this SQL code needs to be deleted and replaced with code that uses proper argument bindings. What you have cannot be used in anything resembling a production environment.